# connection disconnect after few seconds in xmpp using openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

i am using openfire 3.9 and strophe at client side , i am using `http-bind` too. Now the issues is , after i connect with a server and leave my application as it is , it disconnects after few seconds , like around 40 sec after it disconnects and it sends `terminate` command to the server.

so is there any way in openfire to keep the connection alive for a longer period of time ?  do i need to set any system properties for the same or need to do some change at client side ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. will sending presence periodically solve the problem?

Comment: no i guess you got to find something related to http-prebind , that might help

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to send `presence` available from a javascript after every 10 seconds , using `setTimeInterval` none of the property at server side works for me so m using this approach.

so ppl don't waste your time in finding `System properties` at server end.

Answer (score 0):

At client side, default keepalive value is 120 seconds. You can update it to 30s depend on your server openfire.

It fixed for me.